# Multiple SSRS servers share one DB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Can multiple SSRS share the same DB?  We're getting into an SSRS customization scenario, which may adversely affect our existing SSRS features, and I wanted to see if it was possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple SSRS instances can be deployed in a Scale-Out scenario, see [Planning for Scale-Out Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630407.aspx).